# Want to display last day of last month in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I want to initially display the last month's last date, for example, this is November, I want to display 31/10/2019. How is it possible?

```
      var date = new Date();
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth())
        const firstDayOfCurrent = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);
        const firstDayOfCurrentMonth = moment(firstDayOfCurrent).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        console.log(firstDayOfCurrentMonth);

 <td><input type="date" value={firstDayOfCurrentMonth} onChange={(e) => { this.state.invoice.InvoiceDateString  = e.target.value; this.setState({ isset: true }); }} required /></td>
```

Comment: There's potential confusion in your question: you mention November yet you cite `31/10/2019` as an example. November's "digit" is 11 and there are only 30 days. Also I don't quite see how this is an issue specific to React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet will give you last date of last month

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth())
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0);
var lastDayOfLastMonth = lastDay.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
```

and your input tag

```
<input type="date" defaultValue={lastDayOfLastMonth } required />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't display it into my field. I edited my question. Can You please check it?

Comment: change onChange event handler like : `onChange={(e) => {
let invoice = this.state.invoice;
invoice.InvoiceDateString  = e.target.value;
this.setState({ isset: true,
    invoice:invoice
     }); 
 }}`

Comment: Can you please help me to display the lastday in my code

Comment: answer updated, verify here : https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-night-le9em

Answer (score 1):

You can take month from current date to take first day of current month and then subtract one day:

```js
const today = new Date();
const firstDayOfCurrentMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), -1);
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), which has a ton of helper functions you could use for that use-case.

For example [lastDayOfMonth](https://date-fns.org/v2.8.0/docs/lastDayOfMonth), which returns the last day of the month.

It also allows tree-shacking, so that you do not import the whole library, but only the functions you use.